# Convergence/divergence of a couple of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to figure out if the following series converge or diverge:

> (1) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^{n+1}}{n^{2}+1}$. This has the $N$-th partial sum $s_N=\sum^{N}\frac{(-i)^{N+1}}{N^{2}+1}$.

My attempt: To show whether or not the series converges, I need to show whether {$S_{N}$} is Cauchy. So I have to see that $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists N_{\epsilon}$ s.t. for all $n,m>N_{\epsilon}$, $|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{(-i)^{n+1}}{n^{2}+1}|<\epsilon$. Where do I go from here?

> (2) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in\theta}/n$ for $0<\theta<2\pi$, $\theta$ fixed.

Not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 7):

When you try to determine the convergence/divergence of a series, always remember that there is not only *one* trick to do it. So if your attempt failed it can either mean that you didn't do it right or that maybe it's just not a right way to go.

For the first one ; using comparison, you can show that it is absolutely convergent since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{(-i)^{n+1}}{n^2+1} \right| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n^2+1} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{n^2} 
$$
and you know that the latter is a convergent series, hence your series converges absolutely.

For the second one, to know what you're looking for, you can informally do this :
\begin{align}
\frac 1i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\theta}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in\theta}}{in} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int e^{in\theta} \, d \theta = \int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (e^{i\theta})^n \, d\theta = \int \frac 1{1-e^{i\theta}} \, d\theta 
\end{align}
and from here you can compute this integral : by letting $u=1-e^{i\theta}$, you have
\begin{align}
\int \frac 1{1-e^{i\theta}}  d\theta & = \int \frac{i}{u(1-u)}  du = -i \int \frac 1{u(u-1)}  du = -i \int \left(  \frac 1{u-1} - \frac 1u \right) \\ du \\\
& = -i \log(u-1) + i \log(u) \\\
& = -i \log(-e^{i\theta}) + i \log(1-e^{i\theta}) \\\
& = i \log \left( \frac{1-e^{i\theta}}{-e^{i \theta}} \right) \\\
& = i \log(1 - e^{-i\theta}).
\end{align}
This made me noticed what I wanted ; the function we're looking for is a logarithm. If you compute the power series for $\log$, you get
$$
\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {z^n}{n}
$$
which means that your series sums to $-\log(1-e^{-i\theta})$, as long as $\theta \neq 0$ (or an integer multiple of $2\pi$). The trickier part comes because $|e^{i\theta}| = 1$, which means it is on the boundary of the disc of convergence of the function $\log(1-z)$. I must say that at the moment I don't know how to deal with it, but I'll try thinking a little more.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Patrick: It's "series", whether in singular or plural form. :)

Comment: @Srivatsan : bleh, my french language got to me. Thanks

Comment: @srivatsan. Patrick gave a good mathematical answer to a mathematical question and you feel the need to criticize his grammar or spelling? Amazing.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum : It's okay, I considered his comment to be relevant.